# Background / border behind and below text (CSS)

Tags: css

I am looking to create this effect with css: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpzVC.png

Since I don't know how this effect is called, I haven't been able to find a solution online and I can't make it work on my own unfortunately.

The effect repeats a few times on different titles with different sizes. The border should begin on the half of the first letter.

Who can help me?

Comment: please share code what you have tried

Comment: I didn't include it because it was close to useless.. I really have no clue where to start with this one. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PJwbWo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the `:after` pseudo class on the span element to accomplish this.

```css
body {
   background: #3E9CE2;
   color: white;
   font-family: sans-serif;
} /* Just for looks */
   
h1 span {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;      
}

h1 span:after {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   content: "";
   background: #DE2F2D;
   z-index: -5;

   height: 22px;
   top: -19px;
   left: 7px;       
}
```

```html
<h1>This is our <span class="offset-background">showcase</span></h1>
```

The position and display attributes on the `span` itself make sure the `:after` element is properly positioned (directly underneath the `span`) and has the same width as the text.

The pseudo element has to define its height and a position offset, as well as a negative z-index to make sure it's drawn behind the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you seem to be looking for. The solution I used is to offset a box around the text and negatively offset the text the same amount.

```css
h1 span { position: relative; display: inline-block; }
.blue-sq{
  background-color:blue;
  display:inline-block;
}
.offset-red{
  position:relative;
  top:22px;
  background-color:red;
  height:18px;
}
.inner-text{
  position:relative;
  top:-22px;
  left:-6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-sq">
  <h1>View our 
    <span class="offset-red">
      <span class="inner-text">showcase</span>     
    </span>
      
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: When you move the text left you don't have any spacing between "our" and "showcase" anymore

Comment: @Padarom has a better answer for your problem in general. If people are looking to avoid pseudo elements my solution works in a similar way.